# Delta Sink Set Screw Not Catching?

Tags: plumbing, sink

The Delta set screw of the faucet handle doesn't catch to the base without eventually falling out as I screw it in. What am I missing? The handle slot is aligned properly before attempting to screw it in.

[image]

Comment: Need a longer set screw?

Comment: @Huesmann That's what I thought. Unfortunately, this set screw is the Delta OEM, so I'm just doing something wrong. (If you know of a longer set screw that'll fit, please let me know - that was my plan B) https://www.amazon.com/Faucet-RP21469-Waterfall-Single-Handle/dp/B00084VQHO?th=1

Comment: Best I can find, the set screw should be a 1/4-28 thread, but that could be wrong.  I'd take the set screw to Home Depot and check it with their thread tool in the Fasteners aisle.  Then you can order a longer one.

Comment: Is the screw not turning anymore or does it keep turning, but doesn`t move.  Normally the grub-screws are headless, so you should be able to keep tightening.

Answer (score 1):

Screw it out till it is no longer visible but not too much.
Place handle the way you think it should go on.

Start screwing in, while pushing the handle down, and gently wiggling left to right. The wiggle will tell you if you are on target or not since the wiggle will eventually become less and then stop.

If you screw all the way in and the screw falls out the handle was to high. Start over. Watch the tilt.

Comment: I get the idea the OP may not be seating it far enough down, but not that you think it's 180° out. https://i.stack.imgur.com/5pOkm.jpg

Comment: @Tetsujin Thank you for making that clear. Yes, the handle slot is in the correct spot with the set screw. I tried screwing it in while holding the handle down/wiggling a few times, but unfortunately had the same result of the screw not catching.